# Installing MDAC on Macintosh with WineTricks

Tags: sql-server, mac-osx, wine

I have been told that it is possible to install MDAC 2.8 on a Macintosh using WineTricks.

DId anyone tried this and can share the experience? Is there somewhere an instructino to follow?

My goal is to enable OSX clients to run a win32 application that connects to SQL Server (using MDAC).

I am not concerned about licenses, i will sell the software + a windows license per every mac client, now my goal is to be able to install on mac not to lose opportunities.

I know: it would be better to have a mac client, it would be better to have a web application, it would be better...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://wiki.winehq.org/NativeOdbc

Also, please use winehq.org for Wine support questions, you'll probably get faster answers.

Comment: This link no longer points anywhere meaningful and the related page cannot be found on the linked site